# simple adding to value in dictionary python

Tags: python

I want to append to dictionary as a second value second value to a dictionary

```
ret = {}
third_value_list =[0,1]
for i in third_value_list:
    #print i
    num_list = [1,2]
    val_list = [0,1]
    dict1 = dict(zip(num_list,val_list))
    print dict1
    num_list2= [1,2]
    val_list2 = [0,6]
    dict2 =dict(zip(num_list2,val_list2))
    print dict2
if set(dict2.items()) - set(dict1.items()):
    print 'true'
    a = set(dict1.items()) - set(dict2.items())
    ret.update (a)
    print ret
    print 'this is before'
    for key in ret:
       ret[key] = [ret[key]]
       ret[key].append(i)
       print ret
```

current output :

{1: 0, 2: 1}

{1: 0, 2: 6}

{1: 0, 2: 1}

{1: 0, 2: 6}

true

{2: 1}

this is before #below is the final output

{2: [1, 1]}

desire output : {2: [1, 0] ,2: [1, 1]}

Comment: That isn't valid Python syntax: you're missing a `:` after your `for` loop declaration

Comment: Why did you think that would work? You can't `.append` to a `dict`. You need to make the value a list, then append to that.

Comment: You don't seem to have understood how dictionaries work. You have to make the value of `ret[2]` a list, and only then you can append another element to it. Also, your `print` statement should be executed after your attempt to append an element. Otherwise you will never achieve the desired output.

Comment: Assuming you are just looking for `ret = {2:[1]}` and then `ret[2].append(i)`

Comment: Could you clarify the relations of input and output values? Where is the key of `2` coming from? Do you want to increase each successive key by 1? If so, why not use a list? Where is the value of `[1,1]` coming from? It doesn't follow from appending any of your lists' values to any other list.

Comment: the second value in each key in final out put comes from i in third value list
everytime it loops i want to append the key value to final dictionary and add i as second value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the anwser for my question is ret [i] = a